# Compile error (use Consolas font in lstlisting)

Tags: fonts, errors, compiling

I think the only problem is `\setmonofont{Consolas}`. To my confused, I had compile the code successfully, however, when I rebuild my OS (Windows 10)，it doesn't work. I've tried a lot of methods but just in vain.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmonofont{Consolas}
\usepackage[UTF8]{ctex}      % Chinese

\geometry{left = 2.0cm, right = 2.0cm, top = 2.5cm, bottom = 2.5cm}  % 控制使用页面尺寸

\begin{document}
    \title{Templates for ACM-ICPC}
    \date{July 5, 2017}
    \author{Phoebus}

    \maketitle               % Creates the titlepage    
    \pagenumbering{gobble}   % Turns off page numbering
    \newpage                 % Starts a new page
    \tableofcontents         % Auto-generate a table of content after compile again.
    \newpage
    \pagenumbering{arabic}   % Turns on page numbering


    \section{Mathmatics}
    \subsection{快速乘法，防止爆long long}

    \begin{lstlisting}[language = C++, numbers=left, numberstyle=\tiny,keywordstyle=\color{blue!70},
commentstyle=\color{red!50!green!50!blue!50},frame=shadowbox, rulesepcolor=\color{red!20!green!20!blue!20},basicstyle=\ttfamily]
// a*k equals Add k-a
typedef long long ll;  

ll quickMul(ll a, ll k, ll m) {    
  ll ret = 0;
  while(k){
    if(k & 1) ret = (ret + a) % m;
    k >>= 1;
    a = (a << 1) % m;
  }
  return ret;
}   
    \end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Huge thanks to your recommendation, and my code is just like follows, I think the only problem is "\setmonofont{Consolas}". To my confused, I had compile the code successfully, however, when I rebuild my OS(windows 10)， it doesn't work. I've tried a lot of methods but just in vain.